# How to uninstall H2 Database from Ubuntu and windows machine?

Tags: h2

How we can **uninstall** H2 Database from Ubuntu and windows machine? I search a lot but nothing worked for me. Please provide solution for both OS's.

Update: I've had followed http://interface101.blogspot.in/2013/12/3-steps-to-run-h2-database-in-ubuntu.html link for installation of H2 server on Unubtu 14.04, but unfortunate no one provides **uninstall** information.

Comment: How did you install it? I assume it is not installed by default.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I've updated my comments below..Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The installation instruction you used was to just download the jar file of H2.

To uninstall, you just have to remove the jar file (`rm ...`).